# Bulk or cut? (pics)

Tags: weight-loss, diet, bodyweight

I don't know anymore.

Info: 20/M/165(75kg)/6'1/16%BF(omron fat loss monitor).

I've been dieting since February (175lb/79kg), and began losing weight two weeks later (when I bought a food scale). I was eating around 1300cals a day, coupled with 17min HIIT and sloppy lifting (apartment complex gym, only did 1x30/30lb chest press, 1x40/60 leg curls).

By the end of the week, I would lose around 1.5lb. Then decided to go all out and get a gym membership and do the Push/Pull/Legs (PPL) program. Two weeks ago I stalled at 165lb(75kg) and got upset and decided to go a little more extreme (I probably messed up my calories that week anyway or my body adjusted, who knows) and do 1000cals or under/a day. Last week I dropped from 165lb(75kg) to 162(73.5kg). Waiting until Saturday for the next weigh in.

My PPL stats: 
(I still don't know how much the barbell weighs in my gym so these could be way higher or lower. Just added 20lb to everthing to be safe.)

Deadlifts: 60lb(27kg)

Barbell rows: Tomorrow.

Seated cable rows: 60lb/27kg(?)

Face pulls: 35lb(17kg)

Hammer curls: 25lb(11kg)

Dumbbell curls: 25lb(11kg)

Bench press: 50lb(22kg)

Overhead press: 40lb(18kg)

Incline dumbbell press: 40lb(18kg)

Triceps pushdowns: 35lb(17kg)

Lateral raises: 25lb(11kg)

Overhead triceps extensions: 20lb(9kg)

Squat: 50lb(22kg)

Romanian Deadlift: 50lb(22kg)

Leg press: No free weights, the sled is heavy already.

Leg curls: 80lb/36kg(?)

I'm cutting because I want to get rid of this gut and thighs that are really annoying. Then I will have well defined muscle tone. But some people are saying to bulk and the gut will go away or do a small bulk and revamp(?). I don't know what's going on anymore.

What should I be doing for my end goal?

Comment: I really doubt you are only eating 1000-1300 calories per day. Perhaps you could add your actual food intake?  Being at a 1000 calories a day (1700 calorie deficit) is usually something that is medically mandated and tracked, that's a pretty severe restriction. Also [see this](http://weightology.net/weightologyweekly/index.php/free-content/free-content/volume-1-issue-4-the-pitfalls-of-body-fat-measurement-parts-3-and-4-bod-pod-and-bioelectrical-impedance-bia/the-pitfalls-of-bodyfat-measurement-part-4-bioelectrical-impedance-bia/) for BIA shortcomings.

Comment: You *really* need to eat more than what you are right now.

Comment: You don't need to cut.  Your muscle mass is too low to be worrying about bulking or cutting.  Squat more frequently, get the big lifts in, eat clean and often (and lots) and you'll get big.

Answer (score 7):

You are skinny-fat. Stop dieting. Lift heavy, eat more: this will make you strong. What you eat should be high-quality food; skip the soda and sweets. Don't think of it as a "bulk"--just eat as much high-quality meat and vegetables as you need to fuel your lifting.

In a few months, after you have some muscle mass, start doing some cardio to lean out. But right now you are weak and skinny and fat. Lifting heavy and eating more will fix that problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're in a pretty good spot to start bulking. If your main concern is your gut, then I'd try doing your best towards a clean bulk. Prioritize your protein (I'd suggest 1g per 1lb of body weight) while keeping sugar low, and a moderate amount of carbs/fat. You can find more detailed information on diet here - http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/graniero1.htm

The main benefits of bulking at this point are that it will allow your body to recover faster between workouts, and in turn lift heavier weights. If you wish to get stronger and appear stronger, this will be the quickest most efficient path to follow. Also, because you're tearing your muscles, a majority of the food you eat (Especially the protein!) will be going to these muscles and not your gut. It likely won't disappear, at least not overnight, but because the rest of your body will be increasing in size, it will become proportional and give you a better figure to cut around in the future.

This will only work if you're sticking to a good gym plan! PPL isn't a bad idea, though I'd say that's more for intermediate and beyond lifters. If you haven't heard of starting strength or stronglifts 5x5, I'd suggest looking at one of those, as they're great for beginners. Don't be afraid to add accessory exercises and cardio if you're on a binge and wish to go above and beyond, they will help!

Answer (score 0):

Taking the barbell weight away we can get a good idea of what weight plates you are lifting in your PPL program. Taking into account that you are 20, 75kg and 6ft 1in.

I only care, and you should (at this stage) about your main lifts:

- Deadlifts: 40lb(~18kg)
- Bench press: 40lb(~18kg)
- Overhead press: 20lb(9kg)
- Squat: 30lb(~13kg)

Honestly, if someone was doing PPL at your height/weight, I would expect those to be the first warm up weights. Everyone is a special snowflake and we are only in competition with yourselves etc. BUT...

**Reality check**, you just aren't experienced enough to benefit from advanced programming. Get back on 5x5 Stronglifts. Everything you said points towards you being skinnyfat, no-one I know ever finished 6 months of 5x5, following the diet advice on the website and stayed skinnyfat if they followed the program to the letter. You are over-assessing your current lifting ability and experience. You are the definition of a beginner.

Finally, **stop cutting!** What are you cutting to show off? At those lifting numbers, you have no real muscle growth that will be visible without starving yourself. Its likely that your gut is showing because your posture is bad and/or your core is not strong, because you aren't lifting any heavy-ass-weight on a regular basis. Lifting heavy weight will help fix both of those things.

#### Summary:

1. Eat at a maintenance calories or more. NOT LESS.
2. Ditch PPL and pick 5x5 Stronglifts back up, do the entire thing.
3. If you follow 5x5 Stronglifts to the letter, you should achieve 5 reps of:

   - Deadlifts: 180lb(~80kg)
   - Bench press: 135lb(~60kg)
   - Overhead press: 90lb(~40kg)
   - Squat: 180lb(~80kg)